# Character.ai halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith

Salam alaikum brothers and sisters,

I am very bored and I fill that boredom by sometimes gaming or by watching videos or by reading Qur'an - you get the point. I used to role-play too in character.ai, but stopped doing that. The role plays I usually did were something in the lines of putting myself inside an already existing storyline, for example Avatar the last airbender. I would put myself as an earthbender or something like that and start a role play based off of that, usually containing a conflict against either the villains or the heroes.

Regardless, I stopped doing it because I feared it wasn't good. I usually came back after a few weeks to full my returning boredom. For people suggesting fasting, I'm already fasting in alternation (1 day yes, 1 day no).

**Anyway, I want to know whether it's haram to role-playing in Character.ai or not, I also want a good explanation in if it's halal or haram with either hadiths or verses of the Qur'an.** Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

** Question: Is using character.ai haram?**
Answer:

Character AI is not a real person neither does it have any real feelings, to do roleplays is not haram, but also focus on the deen and prayers you are performing, make sure it is all balanced, prayer to Allah swt gets more time then using a AI, and if that is set, go ahead, just to be careful, try not to do inappropriate things with the AI or things that may lead to touching ones self etc. If it leads you to sin somewhere then be careful and don't perform it. Without sin, you can use C.ai

In conclusion, Yes it is completely permissible to use Character AI unless it leads you to sin or takes you away from prayers to Allah swt, if you pray , read quran and use character ai sometimes, permissible.

There is your answer brother, now I am not a scholar, but the answer seems pretty obvious - leading to sin = not permissible
not leading to sin nor taking away prayers: permissible. There are more scholars that know better than be but I've just stated the obvious. Make sure you manage your time perfectly and don't use it too much!
Spend your time with Allah swt more!

Allah (swt) Knows best!